# Mongdb skipping inserts when creating initial collection

Tags: java, mongodb

Seems that when the collection is initially created there a period where you can't insert docs. So running the code below I only get the first insert.

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongo.getDB( "workqueue" );
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("jobs");

coll.insert(new BasicDBObject("desc", "test1"));
coll.insert(new BasicDBObject("desc", "test2"));
coll.insert(new BasicDBObject("desc", "test3"));
```

However, if I put a Thread sleep in between each insert I do get all 3. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think this is due to writeconcern, if you activate it this will prolly go away, you were to put `mongo.writeConcern(WriteConcern.FSYNC_SAFE)` into the second line what do you get?

Comment: Are you on driver version 2.10 ?. 2.10 onwards default mode is  WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED whereas in previous modes it was  WriteConcern.NORMAL.

Comment: You are using the older class Mongo - if you are on a recent driver version, switch to MongoClient.   As you are, in unsafe mode the inserts are happening, they just take a while.  They are not rejected, they are queued.